# extract the filename from MQ Message header

Tags: jms, ibm-mq

Iam using Websphere MQ V8.
I need to get the filename from the header in incoming message file. Is there any properties or default methods available to get it.

Sample File:

[image: sample message header]

Answer (score 0):

The file ame you show in the non-hex dump of your message was put there by the sending application. You should ask the sending application how it was put in there, so that you can know how to pull it out.

Alternatively, show the hex version of your message as well and we might be able to help you further. All the important stuff is not visible to us in your screen shot.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like an RFH version 1 header (not RFH2) but as Morag said, we need to see a hex dump of the message.  There are lots of tools to see the hex dump of the message.  i.e. amqsbcg, MO71, MQ Visual Edit, etc...

From the manual:

The RFH header guidelines only allow for a single header to exist in a message. The fixed binary set of properties is followed by a variable set of name/value pairs.

- strucid
- version
- struclength
- encoding
- codedcharsetid
- format
- flags
- namevaluestring

The filename is in the "namevaluestring" section and as Morag said, you need to have a discussion with the sending application to understand the format they used.

Finally, if this is a new sending application being developed then tell the developer to NOT use RFH version 1 but rather message properties.